# uiwebview slow after javascript call to document.body.innerHTML += someString

Tags: javascript, uiwebview

After I call

```
NSString* javaScript = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"document.body.innerHTML += '%@';", stringToAppend];
[self.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:javaScript];
```

on my UIWebview scrolling becomes slow and choppy. I assume this is because it is loading new html as it scrolls.

Is there a way to force it to load all the html at once so that its not so choppy?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

[self.webView loadHTMLString:stringToAppend baseURL: @"./"]